# Recording and Saving the Screen using C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to write an application that records and saves the screen in C++ on the windows platform. I'm not sure where to start with this. I assume I need some sort of API, (FFMPEG, maybe OpenGL?). Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by looking at Windows remote desktop protocol, maybe some programming libraries are provided for that.

I know of a product that intercepts calls into the Windows GDI dll and uses that to store the screen drawing activities.

A far more simpler approach would be to do screenshots as often as possible and somehow minimize redundant data (parts of the screen that didn't change between frames).

If the desired output of your app is a video file (like mpeg) you are probably better off just grabbing frames and feeding them into a video encoder. I don't know how fast the encoders are these days. Ffmpeg would be a good place to start.

If the encoder turns out not fast enough, you can try storing the frames and encoding the video file afterwards. Consecutive frames should have many matching pixels, so you could use that to reduce the amount of data stored.